# Setup multinode Hadoop cluster using virtual machines on my laptop

Tags: hadoop, vmware

I have a windows 7 laptop and **I need to setup hadoop (mutlinode) cluster** on it.

**I have the following things ready -**

- virtual softwares, i.e. virtualbox and vmware player.
- Two virtual machines, i.e.

  Ubuntu - for Hadoop master and

  Ubuntu - for (1X) Hadoop slave

  Has anyone done a setup of such a cluster using Virtual machines on
  your laptop ?

If yes please help me to install it.

I've searched over google but I am not getting how to configure this multi-node cluster on hadoop using VMs?

How to run two Ubuntu OS on windows 7 using VMware or virtualbox?

Should we use same Ubuntu version VM image or 
vm images with different versions of Ubuntu linux?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can use ubuntu two node. I am using five nodes(1 master, 4 datanodes).
If you want install multi node in vm ware.
Just download ubutnu from this link: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop
And install two machine. And install java and openssh.
And download shell script for multinode from this link::
https://github.com/tonyreddy/Apache-MultiNode-Insatallation-Shellscript

And try it .....
All the best............

Comment: Thanks for reply. But how do i run two virtual machines in my single laptop using vmware player? I've never used vmplayer? please can you just tell me step by step how you done it

Comment: "install two machine." I didn't get this statement of yours, does that mean i need to machines?

Comment: You need install vmware and you can install multiple nodes in that.

Comment: I've installed VMWare player 6, I'm not getting the multiple node option.

Comment: No you need to install vmware not vmplayer

Comment: vmware has lots of products, one of them is VMware Player which free version.                                           https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/downloads ,the link shows a list of vmware products. Out these which one you used for installation? or else please provide me a link for downloading the vmware

Comment: Hi you can download vmware workstation from this link:  https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/details?productId=293&downloadGroup=WKST-902-WIN

Comment: And install this vmware and you can install multiple nodes in this

Answer (score 1):

Since you're running Hadoop on your laptop, obviously you're doing it for learning purposes or building POC or functional debugging.

Instead of going through the hassles of installing and setting up Hadoop and related Big-Data softwares, you can simply install a pre-configured pseudo-distributed VM.

Some good options are:

- [Cloudera QuickStart VM](http://www.cloudera.com/content/support/en/downloads/quickstart_vms/cdh-5-1-x1.html)
- [Hortonworks Sandbox](http://hortonworks.com/products/hortonworks-sandbox/#install)

I've been using the Cloudera's VM on my laptop for quite sometime now and it's been working great.

Answer (score 0):

Cloudera and Hortonworks are the fastest way to get it up and running.

**Make sure you have enough RAM installed on your laptop for the Operating system already running**, else your laptop will restart abruptly often while you use the Virtual machines.

> Let me give you an example -

If you are using *Windows 10*, it needs *3-5GB RAM* to be used to work smoothly,
This means if you load a *Virtual Machine of 5GB* size in your RAM, *Windows may crash* when it *does not* find *enough RAM* to operate.

You must *upgrade the RAM from 8GB to 12GB or best 16GB* for smooth operation of your laptop.

Hope it helps